# When should we avoid "to"?

Tags: prepositions, american-english, infinitives, prepositional-phrases

I was reading a novel and in the novel I read a sentence, which did not sound fine to me.

**From the novel:**

> He always escaped to **go study**.

But I knew it was perfectly (as I trust the writer and I am a non-native English speaker) fine there, but I need to know where and when should I avoid *to* before some words (**maybe they are adverbs**)? 
 I also know that we do not use *to* before them (**as they are adverbs**):

> Home, out, outside, somewhere, anywhere, nowhere, abroad, downtown,
>   downstairs, upstairs, underground, there, here, in, inside.

We do not use *to* before them as well (I think study comes in this category):

> go play, going shopping, go shopping.

My question is that are they also adverbs? if yes then please let me know the list when I should avoid *to* before them.

Comment: To me the question is unclear.  I only have one sentence template to try to understand: **He always escaped to go study.**  For example, I find no problem with "to go home, to go outside, to go play, to go shopping -- all of which fit the same sentence pattern that you demonstrated.  Perhaps you could write some other complete sentences to demonstrate context it would be more clear.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis I wonder if the question is why the writer didn't write "He always escaped to go **to** study."  That is, even though there's a "to" in the sentence, OP is asking about the possible one that's been omitted.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, Perhaps OP is saying that often one comes across phrases like "escaped to go to the market" and we don't say "go the market" or "go market".

Comment: @CoolHandLouis That's another possibility.  If it's the verb market, though, we can say "escaped to go market [his wares]," of course.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, please check out my updated answer and see if it makes sense.  Any comments/rebuttals/etc. are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all we need more context to comment on that sentence.

We generally use ***escape from doing something*** or ***escape doing something*** synonymously.

So your quoted sentence sounds like **He escaped something to go study**

Now coming to your confusion - ***go study***

It's not any elliptical form of ***go to study***, rather it means ***go and study***. It's more common in American informal language, mostly in conversation.

***Go shopping***, ***go playing*** are all different construction, where ***shopping*** and ***playing*** are gerund.

Hope this helps. Please write back to me if there is any confusion about my answer or if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. So, can we use "go to study" instead of go study? Or "go to study" is completely wrong?

Comment: No it's not wrong, it's another way of saying. Basically in writing and formal situation you should stick to "go to study", instead of "go study". "Go and study" is still okay, but I think "go study" is too informal.

Answer (score 4):

I think OP's issue might be "when to use to" as in "He left to go to the market."  We don't say, "He left to go the market." nor do we say "He left to go market."

There are a couple rules here to follow:

- **He left to go *verb*:** (Emphasis is on the action of the verb especially when the reason is fairly short.)

  - He left to go **study.**
  - He left to go **play.**
  - He left to go **buy something at the store.** (verb first, place second)
  - He left to go **see the movie, *Batman*.**
  - He left to go **see *Batman*.**
  - "I'm going to go **do some laundry.**" (Here, "do some laundry" is an action. Compare with "I'm going to go **to do some laundry**" where **"to do some laundry"** is emphasized as a **reason** for going.)
- **He left to go to *verb*:** (Emphasis is on the verb as a reason, used more often with the subordinate clause is more complicated and meaning of "in order to" is emphasized.)

  - He left to go to see his doctor about his stomach problems.
- **He left to go [Indefinite place or relative direction]:**

  - He left to go **somewhere.**
  - He left to go **outside.**
- **He left to go to [Definite or indefinite named place]:**

  - He left to go **to the store to buy something.** (place first, verb/reason second)
  - He left to go **to a store.**
  - He left to go **to the store.** (typically "to buy something", but could be some other reason: maybe he works there, maybe to meet someone, etc.)
  - He left to go **to the dance.** (signifying a place - he may or may not dance there.)
  - He left to go **to a place.**
- **To go and *verb*** (Emphasis is equally on both going and *verbing*):

  - He left too go and see New York.

There are some more subtle/intricate reasons for using "to go X" vs. "to go to X", which I think would require a more substantial answer:

- "Most of our money **will have** to go **to pay the bills**." (Some tense/aspect requires "to verb".)
- "Most of our money **will have** to go **pay the bills**."* (This is idiomatically inferior. The use of "to pay" helps as a discourse marker when sentences become more complex.  In other words, there is less ellipsis -- dropping of words -- in complex sentences.)
- I got a long way to go to get to where he's at. ("A long way to go" is it's own phrase.)
- I got a long way to go to get where he's at. (Less optimal because "to go" doesn't fit so well with "get where he's at.")

Comment: +1 I think this is a good taxonomy of examples, and covers a bunch of the most common cases.

Comment: But "to go X" is, I suspect, not correct in many dialects, eg British English. If I read "to go study" I would assume the writer was North American.

Answer (score 3):

To briefly address the aspect of your question about adverbs:

"To go" is the *infinitive* form of the verb, and you can put an adverb between the two parts of the infinitive:  "To boldly go where no one has gone before", or "to briefly address ..."

This is called a *split infinitive*, and many people believe that it is incorrect in English. Though it can be *inelegant* to split an infinitive with an adverb, it is not wrong. Many distinguished speakers of English throughout history have used split infinitives and they will be understood by any native speaker. Some people consider it better form to say "to go boldly..." or "to address briefly..." but it typically makes no difference to the meaning of the sentence.

Oddly enough, people who tell you that it is wrong to put an adverb between "to" and a verb, never tell you that it is wrong to put an adjective between "the" and a noun. If "to boldly go" is wrong then shouldn't "the green dragon" also be wrong?

Comment: "the green dragon" can't be wrong because nothing else rhymes so perfectly with "by the flagon"